# JavaScript doesn't link to HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I'm struggling to get javascript file linked to HMTL. I've made sure that the HTML & javascript file are saved as 'index.html' & 'script.js', and saved them in the same folder. But when trying to access the html file in Chrome, the javascript doesn't appear, either in Console of the Dev Tool.
Please see below the code I'm writing in Sublime Text. Could you please advise me what I'm doing wrong here? Thanks a lot !

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <html>
    <head>
        <title>JavaScript</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Javascript in HTML</h1>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
        
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Show the contents of your JavaScript code. Also, what does say the network tab? Is loading the file and what is the received code?

Comment: Hi Jorge, Please see below the content of the javascript code: console.log("hello");
The network tab just says : Javascript in HTML - the paragraph

Comment: Make sure that *JavaScript* is enabled in the browser. https://www.whatismybrowser.com/guides/how-to-enable-javascript/chrome

Comment: thank you. It was already enabled

Comment: @Glenna, you should post your JavaScript in the body of the Question, not the comments, even as minimal as your JS is.

Comment: For your next question, please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, specially the "Help others reproduce the problem" part. Also, the network tab is the one in the Dev Tool (F12), which shows your script.js network request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going off the comments, the code `console.log("hello");` will display "hello" in the console of your browser, not in the body of your HTML page. This is often accessed by tapping the `F12` key.

If you want your text to show up in the HTML, you need to give it an HTML element for the text to be displayed, then use JavaScript to find the element and update the text.

```js
document.getElementById("textGoesHere").innerText = "hello";
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
    <head>
        <title>JavaScript</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="#">
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Javascript in HTML</h1>
        <div id="textGoesHere" />
    </body>
</html>
```

The caveat to that is you can't run the JavaScript correctly until the HTML is generated, so declaring it in the `HEAD` tag, like people tend to do, you need to put the JavaScript in a method, then call that method from the `BODY` event of `onload`.

```html
<body onload="UpdateText()">
```

```js
function UpdateText()
{
    document.getElementById("textGoesHere").innerText = "hello";
}
```

Since this is fairly basic JavaScript and HTML, I'm going to suggest you use a tutorial to get started programming, such as:

https://www.codecademy.com/learn/introduction-to-javascript

It's much easier to learn the basics from a course than try to stumble your way through, trying to learn piecemeal by banging your head on everything. I have some experience in doing both. Believe me, a tutorial/class is less painful. ;-)

Answer (score -1):

try out this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
    <head>
        <title>JavaScript</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="#">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Javascript in HTML</h1>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Saroj, thank you for your response. I've tried it but still doesn't work. Only the h1 paragraph is showing.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please add always some explanations to your answers.